# php code not working working on xampp

Tags: php

I am new in php field.
i'm using xampp and it's on. and php also activated.

i wrote this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$x=5;
$y=6;
$z=$x+$y;
echo $z;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The output window is empty. I don't know what the error is.
Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: So a page with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` works? Does the page you created end in `.php`?

Comment: try adding this `echo "<p>".$z."</p>";` or try just running `phpinfo();`

Comment: <?php phpinfo(); ?> this thing also not working. and the extension is ".php".

Comment: Maybe you are opening wrong file? How you are trying to open it?

Comment: i am working on Notepad++.
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/doctrinetest/welcome.php
here is the full path

Comment: How you trying to open that file? What is URL in browser?

Comment: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/doctrinetest/welcome.php
that's the url in browser.

Comment: Try http://localhost/doctrinetest/welcome.php

Comment: You need to open this via Apache.

Comment: Wekk Thanks @Ayesh K this local host thing worked for me :). Now how to gives you +1?

Comment: I think it's stupid this post was closed... it's a real problem, I suffered the same problem. The reason is the short_open_tags in your PHP.INI file: I think you might be using short tag <? ?> or <?= ?> instead of <?php ?>.
Check you php.ini. It locates at \path\to\xampp\php\php.ini. The short_open_tag should be On.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer based on comments.

PHP file must be interpreted by web server (in your case - **apache with php extension**, which is part of XAMPP), which executes PHP code and sends script output/result via http protocol to web browser.

To execute PHP script and show it's result you have to use HTTP, like this: `http://localhost/doctrinetest/welcome.php`.

`c:\xampp\htdocs` directory is "served" at `http://localhost/` URL.

Opening that file via filesystem (not using apache server) will output blank page, because browser is not supposed to execute PHP. However, that blank page will contain your static HTML part of code.

It looks like, you dont understand how PHP works. **You need to read some books about web fundamentals.**

Eventually you can visit http://thenewboston.org or http://phpacademy.org - they have very good educational videos.

Comment: //Opening that file via filesystem (not using apache server) will output blank page, because browser is not supposed to execute PHP. However, that blank page will contain your static HTML part of code.//

@Kamil   

would you please try to answer my question ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453660/create-php-code-not-working-screen-becomes-white-in-xampp?noredirect=1#comment68152934_40453660

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the file is not interpreted as PHP. Make sure that the file has the extension php.

The reason why you don't see the php code is that the tags prevent that, but you should find them in the source code.

You should check that you access the file via http and not directly with the browser. So you should have something like `http://localhost/script.php` in your address bar.

Also make sure that you have somewhere in your apache config such lines:

```
#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/www/php/php5ts.dll"
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/www/php/php5apache2_2.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Type of file is php. i'm using window 7 type of file is "PHP file"

Comment: @rekire
I have problems in xampp white screen . Would you please try to explain?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453660/create-php-code-not-working-screen-becomes-white-in-xampp?noredirect=1#comment68152934_40453660

Answer (score 1):

Please google for: How to install XAMPP. When its done, open in browser

```
http://localhost/
```

to see if it is working or not.

This is not a real question, before asking something you should learn something.

Comment: to see xampp working or not i type this http://localhost/. and there i can see that, that xampp is working.

Comment: now put to c:\xampp\htdocs file named index.php and inside this file add <?php phpinfo(); ?> and try to call again localhost url.