# Create PHP code not working [screen becomes white] in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

[image: Image 1]

[image: image host]

I was working on **XAMPP** . After upgrading **phyMyAdmin** separately in **XAMPP**, as you can see (in image - 1) I wrote some simple codes :

```
SELECT *
FROM db
```

my database name : **mysql**

output was correct . (in image - 1)

When I pressed **Create PHP code** , my screen became white (like image - 2) .

Even there was no error message . I tried reinstalling **XAMPP** and configuring **phpMyAdmin** again but nothing happened .

Here is **config.inc.php** :

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in documentation in the doc/ folder
 * or at <https:docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

/**
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie. Needs to be 32 chars long.
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/**
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlport'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Storage database and tables */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_settings'] = 'pma__designer_settings';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['export_templates'] = 'pma__export_templates';

/**
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/**
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Whether to display icons or text or both icons and text in table row
 * action segment. Value can be either of 'icons', 'text' or 'both'.
 * default = 'both'
 */
$cfg['RowActionType'] = 'icons';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * Possible values: 25, 50, 100, 250, 500
 * default = 25
 */
$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false    allow editing
 *   'blob'   allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'noblob' disallow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'    disallow editing
 * default = 'blob'
 */
$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = false;

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 * default = 25
 */
$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/**
 * Whether or not to query the user before sending the error report to
 * the phpMyAdmin team when a JavaScript error occurs
 *
 * Available options
 * ('ask' | 'always' | 'never')
 * default = 'ask'
 */
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'always';

/**
 * You can find more configuration options in the documentation
 * in the doc/ folder or at <https:docs.phpmyadmin.net/>.
 */
```

I could not find any clue in error log :

```
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.288762 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.500746 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.552765 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.552765 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.552765 2016] [core:notice] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:31.560763 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8828:tid 560] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7200
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:32.256744 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7200:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:32.456749 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7200:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:18:32.500765 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7200:tid 600] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.030532 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.249280 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.280532 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.280532 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.280532 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.280532 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7320:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7120
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:46.936784 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7120:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:47.108656 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 7120:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:25:47.155539 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7120:tid 556] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.745420 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.807959 2016] [core:warn] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.917293 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.964169 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH00455: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.964169 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jul  1 2016 11:09:37
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.964169 2016] [core:notice] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:54.964169 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3436:tid 568] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 408
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:55.620420 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 408:tid 604] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:55.792294 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 408:tid 604] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Nov 07 00:53:55.839188 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 408:tid 604] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Comment: Try to read error logs

Comment: Where I can find error log ? @u_mulder

Comment: Search here or in google.

Comment: ok . still searching .

Comment: you should not be using phpMyAdmin to write php for you

Comment: error log added

Comment: Enable error logging for php itself that should give you more hints what goes wrong. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/995926